# Setting attributes both in FXML and in CSS

Tags: css, javafx, java-8, fxml

If I am trying to set the same attribute in FXML and in a class definition in CSS, I would expect that the attribute set in FXML is considered more specific than the one from CSS.

For example, if I have a control such as

```
<Label styleClass="myLabel" prefHeight="40.0">
```

and, at the same time, a CSS definition such as

```
Label.myLabel {
    -fx-pref-height: 100px;
}
```

I would expect the label to have a height of 40 px. Instead, it has 100 px.
Is there a way to make the attribute in the FXML have precedence?

Comment: In HTML, browsers simply map presentational attributes to CSS rules with specificity lower than that of a * rule. This allows browsers to implement all layout with CSS alone, while always allowing authors to override presentational attributes with CSS. On the flip side it is not possible to force a presentational attr to override a CSS rule. Depending on how CSS is implemented in JavaFX, this may or may not be the case for FXML.

Comment: @BoltClock So mapped to the "browser domain", this is indeed wanted behaviour? So it might be the same in FXML. Thank you for your note!

Comment: I would say they're between browser and author domain - more specific than any browser defaults, and less specific than author CSS (including external links, <style>, inline styles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the (so far) absence of a qualified answer, I can only guess:

While one could expect that the FXML attributes have about the same specificity as an inline style definition, they haven't any relation.

The reason for this is the evaluation order: the FXML attributes are evaluated at an earlier time than and completely independent of the CSS definitions. That's why the CSS definitions completely overwrite the attribute definitions, making them obsolete.

---

Now it is more than a guess: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/StyleableProperty.html) I just found that the order of precedence is

> 1. a style from a user agent stylesheet in `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(java.lang.String)`
> 2. value set from code, for example calling `Node.setOpacity(double)`
> 3. a style from an author stylesheet in `Scene.getStylesheets()` or `Parent.getStylesheets()`
> 4. a style from `Node.setStyle(java.lang.String)`

assuming that pre-setting a value in the FXML is equivalent to a value set from code.